# Pairwise independent gaussians

Tags: derandomization, pr.probability

Given $X_1,\ldots,X_k$ (i.i.d. gaussians with mean $0$ and variance $1$), is it possible (how?) to sample (for $m=k^2$) $Y_1, \ldots, Y_m$ such that 
$Y_i$'s are pairwise independent gaussians with mean $0$ and variance $1$.

Comment: I don't have a proof for this, but it seems to me that $Y_{ij} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} (X_i + X_j)$ might do the trick ? it's Gaussian by 2-stability arguments, and seems like it would be pairwise independent ?

Comment: @Suresh, $E[(X_i+X_j)(X_i+X_k)] = E[X_i^2] = 1$ so it does not seem to work.

Comment: @Anindya De: If I were you I would ask this first on MathOverflow.

Comment: hmm. I see. was trying to simulate the ax + b type constructions.

Comment: I don't know why, but I find the MO answer to this question quite hilarious (apart from the pointer to stats.SE): http://mathoverflow.net/questions/46180/how-to-sample-pairwise-independent-gaussians

Comment: @Suresh: agree about that answer on MO. :) I would phrase the question a little bit differently though, I am not even sure $\omega(k)$ is a common notion for probability theorists. Let's see if I can help there.

Comment: Please rephrase your question so it doesn't admit the trivial answer that was given on mathoverflow. Why do you care?

Comment: @Anindya De: I agree with Warren, you may want to clarify the complexity of the sampling, e.g. you want it to be computable in $P$. (but I think the transformations from uniform to normal and vice versa *are* efficient.)

Comment: What I was looking for was something like taking linear combinations (which obviously does not work) or polynomials etc. (which don't work immediately) but I cannot really think of any reasonable notion which Shai's answer on mathoverflow does not meet.

Comment: maybe you should update the question pointing out the answer on MO ?

Comment: Do you need a jointly Gaussian distribution? If so, what you need seems to be impossible since such a distribution is determined by its covariance matrix and thus, pairwise independence and full independence would be the same.

Comment: @MCH: My interpretation of the question is that as long as every pair among Y_i’s is independent (and therefore jointly Gaussian), the joint distribution for more than two variables can be anything.  Are you saying that this already implies that full independence?  If so, can you elaborate why?

Answer (score 4):

The posting on MathOverflow tells how to go from a small number of independent Uniform[0,1] random variables to a larger number of pairwise-independent Uniform[0,1] random variables. You can of course go back and forth between Uniform[0,1] and Gaussian by inverting the CDF. But that requires numerical analysis as the CDF is not closed-form.

However, there is a simpler way to from Gaussian to uniform. Given two independent Gaussians $X_1, X_2$, the angle $\arctan(X_1/X_2)$  is uniform in the range $[0,2 \pi]$.

Similarly, the Box-Muller method transforms two independent Uniform[0,1] variables into two independent Gaussian random variables.

Using these two transformations, you consume two Gaussians to produce a uniform or two uniforms to produce a Gaussian. So there is only a factor of $O(1)$ in the sampling efficiency. Furthermore, no inversion of the Normal cdf is required.

Answer (score -2):

This construction does **NOT** give pairwise independent variables (indeed, $|Y_{i,j}| = |Y_{i,j'}|$ below) as asked by Anindya, but it gives pairwise uncorrelated variables which is enough for getting good concentration bounds for the sum through Chebyshev's inequality (and this is many times the end goal).

For each distinct pair $(i,j) \in {[k] \choose 2}$, let $Y_{i,j} = |X_i| \cdot \sigma(X_i X_j)$, where $\sigma(\cdot)$ is the sign function. It's clear that each $Y_{i,j}$ is a normal variable with mean 0 and variance 1. To see that they are orthogonal, for $(i,j) \neq (i',j')$, note that $$\mathbb{E}[Y_{i,j}Y_{i',j'}] = \mathbb{E}[|X_i X_{i'}| \cdot \sigma(X_i X_{i'} X_j X_{j'})]$$
which can be easily checked to equal 0 by looking at the various cases of possible equalities between $i,i',j,j'$.

P.S.: A previous version falsely claimed pairwise independence.

Comment: I cannot follow why the mean of the product being zero would imply independence.

Comment: @TsuyoshiIto: Your criticism was correct, of course. I've still left this answer up, as I think it's interesting.

Comment: If you want to keep your post, please use necessary precaution to avoid confusing the readers.  You may argue that the current version (revision 3) of your post does not state anything incorrect.  True, but the question asks something, and your post answers something else without stating so.  Please understand that it is extremely confusing to the readers.